# Тип записи float занести в текстовый редактор

Tags: c#, arraylist, float

мне нужно создать файл в программе и занести в него данные, сгенерированные с помощью объекта класса Random типа float, но выводится int, в чем моя ошибка?

```
static class Fileprocessing
    {
        static  ArrayList lst = new ArrayList();
        public static void WriteFile(string s)
        {
            StreamWriter f = new StreamWriter(@s);
            Random rnd = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            { //"Вывод в текстовый файл:"
                f.WriteLine((float)rnd.Next(100));
            }
            f.Close();
        }
        public static void ReadFile(string s)
        {
            StreamReader f = new StreamReader(@s);
            while (!f.EndOfStream)
            {
                lst.Add(float.Parse(f.ReadLine()));
            }
            f.Close();
            lst.Sort();
            foreach (object x in lst) Console.WriteLine((float)x);
        }
        public static void WriteFileResult(string s)
        {
            StreamWriter f = new StreamWriter(@s);
            for (int i = 0; i < lst.Count; i++)
            { //"Вывод в текстовый файл:"
                f.WriteLine(lst[i]);
            }
            f.Close();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Что такое `Random типа float` и как вы поняли, что `но выводится int`?

Comment: Как вы думаете, что тут вообще происходит? `f.WriteLine((float)rnd.Next(100));`

Comment: Просто добавьте форматирование `f.WriteLine(((float)rnd.Next(100)).ToString("F2"));` или так `f.WriteLine(((float)rnd.Next(10000) / 100).ToString("F2"));`

Comment: @tym32167 вывод рандомных чисел в текстовый файл

Comment: @aepot спасибо большое:)